How can I append dynamic value with Href static URL <a href="someUrl" + recordId>
HTML:
<template>
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered">

            <tbody>
                <template for:each={accList.data} for:item="acc">
                  <lightning-layout multiple-rows key={acc.id}>
                   <lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto" padding="around-small" size="12" small-device-size="12"
                                      medium-device-size="12" large-device-size="12">
                    
                    <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-max-medium-table_stacked container">
                       <span class="logo slds-m-right_small"> 
                        <img src={acc.Logo__c} alt={altText} /></span>
                       
                  
                    <span> <b> {acc.Name}</b></span></br></br>

                    <span class="slds-p-left_large"></span>
                     <span class="logo slds-m-right_small cnt">Country Served:</span></br>
                   
                       <div class="country lineClamp" onclick={handleClick}><b> {acc.Country_or_Countries_Served__c}</b></div></br>


                        accountId = {acc.Id}
                        <a class="slds-button slds-button_neutral slds-m-right_small btn" href="i-need-a-broker/?BrokerId=accountId">Contact Broker</a>
                        <a class="slds-button slds-button_destructive" href="broker-info/?varAccountId=accountId">View Details</a>

                        </br></br>
                           </div>
</lightning-layout-item>
                </lightning-layout>
                </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</template>

JS:
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getBrokerAccountDeatils from '@salesforce/apex/BrokerAccountDetailsCtrl.getBrokerAccountDeatils';
export default class Broker_Landing_Page extends LightningElement {
    accList
    @wire(getBrokerAccountDeatils)
    accList;
}


Instead of using href, you can use lightning-button.
html
<template> 
       <lightning-button label="Contact Broker" onclick={navigateToLink}>
       </lightning-button> 
</template>`

JS
import { LightningElement,wire} from 'lwc';
import getBrokerAccountDeatils from '@salesforce/apex/BrokerAccountDetailsCtrl.getBrokerAccountDeatils';
export default class Broker_Landing_Page extends LightningElement {
    accList
    @wire(getBrokerAccountDeatils)
    accList;

   navigateToLink() {
         if (accList) {
            const url = `broker-info/?varAccountId=${accList}`;
            window.location.href = url;
        } else {
            console.error('Account ID is not provided');
        }
    }
}

